# NetSuite SuiteCommerce Advanced - Customize Category Sorting

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

Currently, in my category page, I only have a sort dropdown option for:

- Sort by relevance
- Sort by price, low to high
- Sort by price, high to low

Is there a way to add or change options for sorting products in category page? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add facets into site setup and simply configure that facets into the configuration. Let me know for more information if needed.

Comment: I won't be able to apply it now because client requirements have changed. thanks for the answer anyway